# passenger nginx rails request failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

nginx rails sometimes gives 404 error and the error log is (works after nginx restart)

```
2014/05/14 13:29:49 [crit] 32228#0: *3138 connect() to /tmp/passenger.1.0.32203/generation-0/request failed (2: No such file or directory) whil$
$76.186, server: 107.170.10.25, request: "GET /api/v1/search.json?radius=25&longitude=77.62598510831594&latitude=12.934331866450355&per=10&page$
2014/05/14 13:29:51 [crit] 32228#0: *3140 connect() to /tmp/passenger.1.0.32203/generation-0/request failed (2: No such file or directory) whil$
2014/05/14 13:29:51 [error] 32228#0: *3140 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 171.76.76.186$
```

If i restart nginx everything works fine. i am using rails 4 passenger  4.0.41 with rvm 1.25.24 
i have used passenger-nginx ubuntu package. instructions from https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04

Answer (score 0):

That problem should go away if you set `passenger_temp_dir /somewhere-appropriate`